# Nagios mysql check service definition configuration?

Tags: mysql, monitoring, network-monitoring, nagios

I'm using the [Consol Labs MySQL Health Check](http://labs.consol.de/nagios/check_mysql_health/) plugin to monitor my MySQL database.

I'd like to change the warning and critical thresholds for the `threads connected` parameter, but have forgotten how.

My check is setup in my `service.cfg` like so:

```
define service {
        use                             mysql-service
        hostgroup_name                  mysql-servers
        check_interval                  1
        service_description             MySQL Threads Connected
        _mysql_mode                     threads-connected
        check_command                   check_mysql_health
}
```

I'm having trouble remembering in which part of the above config I define my thresholds?

I've tried, `check_mysql_health:20:40` & `check_mysql_health! -w 20: -c 40:`
but they both didn't work.

Anyone know how i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a fundamental concept here. Read the [Macros and how they work](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/4/en/macros.html) docs page.

Roughly: create a new service definition with a `command_line` like `/path/to/your/plugins/check_mysql_health --warning $ARG1$ --critical $ARG2$`. (Note that these are standard Nagios [threshhold ranges](https://www.nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html#THRESHOLDFORMAT).)

Also be sure to read `check_mysql_health --help` or see the [Consol Labs site](https://labs.consol.de/nagios/check_mysql_health/) for more information about using the plugin.